# Docker fails in hello-world: failed to register layer: remount /, permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I just installed docker on a **Databricks** cluster node and here is the os info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I put docker info at the end because it's too long.

I am using **ROOT** user changed the root directory to `/tmp` with 777 permission, but when I run `docker pull` or `docker run`, it always tries to remount and says permission denied as follows:

```
docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
719385e32844: Extracting [==================================================>]  2.457kB/2.457kB
failed to register layer: remount /, flags: 0x84000: permission denied
```

I tried to run `mount -o remount,rw /` using `ROOT` user but still failed:

```
mount: /: cannot remount /var/lib/lxc/base-images/release__13.3.x-snapshot-photon-scala2.12__databricks-universe__13.3.5__6980ecb__4a6d433__jenkins__f40af97__format-3 read-write, is write-protected.
```

I tried to check mount info on Databricks notebook by running `display(dbutils.fs.mounts())`, it only work within the directory `/dbfs` and this directory is not acceptable for Docker.

How to address this issue? Any help is appreciated.

**Docker info**:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.7
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.21.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 24.0.7
 Storage Driver: vfs
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
 runc version: v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-1048-aws
 Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 24.9GiB
 Name: 1107-091517-sgtior5x-10-201-64-203
 ID: 3d720a3d-2121-42d7-9e47-32b9e675241b
 Docker Root Dir: /tmp
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```